# How can I add a place holding byte in my array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I currently have this byte array:

```
public byte[] ToByteArray()
{
    List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
    byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(MsgID));
    byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Status));
    byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Value));
    byteList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TagName.Length));
    byteList.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TagName));
    return byteList.ToArray();
}
```

I'm using this array to send over TCP and as such I need each element to hold a set position. This worked fine for me until I changed `value` into a dynamic variable which can be either a `int16` or `int32`. the data type is specified in the `msgID` so the client knows how to handle the received byte message. However since a converted `int16` is half the byte length of a `int32` I need some kind of placeholder between `value` and `TagName.Length`.

I was thinking about using `InsertRange` at index 7 at but I'm not sure how the list will handle the missing 2 bytes.

Comment: If you convert a int16 to int32, it will automatically add some 0 at the front. And you can do that cast without any danger of loosing data. The compiler will even do it implicitly. Ideally of course you should not have a dynamic type to begin with. Those can mess up a lot of things, including the return type of functions.

Comment: @Christopher If I convert an unsigned int16 into a signed 32bit will it create any issues? I only set it to dynamic so I can pass `value` into my method since:

    public Messaging(ushort cmd, bool stat, dynamic val, string tag)
    {
        MsgID = cmd;
        Status = stat;
        Value = val;
        TagName = tag;
    }

Comment: That should be no issue at all. There is no value of unsigned int16 that signed int32 can not also hold. If you were converting from 32 to 16 or signed to unsigned, there would be a danger of data loss. But from signed int16 to unsgined int32? The compiler will do that implicitly if you just assing that int16 to a int32 variable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators#example-1

Comment: Thanks @Christopher. Do you really think the dynamic value isn't the best route? I'm only using it since the value I'm trying to pass in can be many different data types (single, int16/32, uint16/32).

Comment: Strong Typisation is your biggest friend, really. Without it, you have issues like you do in PHP or JavaScript: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/ Dynamic is a "nessesary evil" when we interact with weakly type languages, WepAPIs, that kind of stuff.

Comment: Great! I'll change it from dynamic to var then. Thanks again @Christopher